# Yocto: root login not accepting after adding packages to IMAGE_INSTALL_append

Tags: yocto, bitbake, imx7

In an imx7saresd  board In yocto , fitIMage and a rootfs , my image gets booted up for a core-image-minimal build using "root" as login and no password set.
Then I use IMAGE_INSTALL_append variable and add few packages , image gets booted up , but then root login is not accepted and I am asked to enter the login name  again and again.

I have kept EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES at default as below

EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES ?= "debug-tweaks"

I dont know , why adding a package using IMAGE_INSTALL_append is creating the issue and not accepting my root login. I am using IMAGE_INSTALL_append as below in my conf/local.conf

IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " blah blah blah"

poky is in warrior branch  here.

Comment: Which packages are you adding? Can you check the contents of `/etc/passwd` in the rootfs - what is the content of the line for `root`?

Comment: I am adding packages like openssh and bluez5 . Content of root are -->       root:x:0:0:root:/home/root:/bin/sh   @Justin

Comment: Okay, the `x` part of `root:x:0:0:root:/home/root:/bin/sh` indicates the password for root is stored in `/etc/shadow`. In that file, there should be a line starting with `root::` if no password is set for the root user. If the line starts with `root:$...` then a password is set, and you will need to check how /etc/shadow is generated by Yocto.